# jQuery UI autocomplete: search 2 huge MySQL tables not linked

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My website references more than 100.000 articles of 20.000 different authors. I would like jQuery UI autocomplete search in two tables, either the article title or the author name.

The two tables are basically:

> Table articles
>
> - title (ex: This is the title)
> - slug (ex: this-is-the-title)
>
> Table author
>
> - name (ex: John Doe)
> - slug (ex: john-doe)

The slug information should be retreived as the search bar will redirect to **article.php** or **author.php** depending of the search result.

My concern is that parsing these two tables like that takes very long, more than 30 seconds:

```
SELECT title, ar.slug, name, au.slug
FROM articles ar,author au
WHERE published = 1
AND (title LIKE :term OR name LIKE :term)
```

The column are already indexed.

Is there a better approach?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your query is so slow is that you have no condition on your `JOIN` and so you are getting a potential result set of 100,000*20,000 i.e. 2B rows that have to be filtered by your `WHERE` clause. Since you don't need any type of relationship between the tables for this query, it would be better to just use a `UNION`, adding a field to distinguish between `author` and `title`:

```
SELECT 'author' AS type, name AS value, slug
FROM author
WHERE published = 1 AND name LIKE :term
UNION
SELECT 'title' AS type, title, slug
FROM articles
WHERE published = 1 AND title LIKE :term
```